# Assigning Roles with MVC SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am trying out "SimpleMembership" in MVC3 via Nuget and have downloaded the sample to play with.
The issue is that I cannot figure out how I would assign a role to a particular user.

In the standard MVC membership you can just use something like:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "StandardUser");
```

However, SimpleMembership only seems to have one method for roles exposed (unless Im being stupid!) which is

```
public void RequireRoles(params string[] roles)
        {
            WebSecurity.RequireRoles(roles);
        }
```

There must be an easy way as the following table was created as part of this nuget package:

```
-TABLE: webpages_Roles
     RoleId , RoleName
```

This is slightly confusing though as in `App_Start/SimpleMembershipMvc3.cs` there is the following:

```
Roles.Enabled = true;
RoleProvider provider3 = Roles.Providers["AspNetSqlRoleProvider"];
        if (provider3 != null)
        {
            RoleProvider provider6 = provider3;
            SimpleRoleProvider provider4 = CreateDefaultSimpleRoleProvider("AspNetSqlRoleProvider", provider6);
            Roles.Providers.Remove("AspNetSqlRoleProvider");
            Roles.Providers.Add(provider4);
        }
```

SimpleRoleProvider function

```
 private static SimpleRoleProvider CreateDefaultSimpleRoleProvider(string name, RoleProvider currentDefault)
            {
                RoleProvider previousProvider = currentDefault;
                SimpleRoleProvider provider = new SimpleRoleProvider(previousProvider);
                NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection();
                provider.Initialize(name, config);
                return provider;
            }
```

Does this package use the built in Role provider? If so, how does it hook up with the tables created by SimpleMembership

- [Simple Membership GIT](https://github.com/anderly/SimpleMembership.Mvc3)
- [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/simplemembership.mvc3)
- [Nuget Package for sample](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleMembership.Mvc3.Sample)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the [Roles API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstorole.aspx) to interact with the Roles. Something like the following should work:

```
if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
    Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");

if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Contains("Administrator"))
    Roles.AddUsersToRole(new[] { model.UserName }, "Administrator");
```

Comment: there is a typo, remove the curly brace at last line :)

Answer (score 2):

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseFile("SecurityDemo.sdf", "Users", "UserID", "Username", true);
```

CHeck out this website. It may be of some help.
http://blog.osbornm.com/archive/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages.aspx

Comment: Not sure why this has been updated, it does not answer the question.